# New tab won't open window.open html and js

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to code a button in HTML that opens a new tab to a website when clicked. However, when it is pressed, it just leads to a white page and nothing happens. Please give advice on what to do

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="editText()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="edit.js"></script>

<!-- This button is supposed to open a new tab to a website -->
<input type="button" value="Run" onclick="open()">
<script type="text/javascsript" src="edit.js"></script>
```

Javascript (edit.js) :

```
function editText() {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Saved!"
}

function open() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com/?client=safari", _blank)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass `__blank` as string

```
window.open("https://www.google.com/?client=safari", '_blank')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, although it did not work. It seems like no matter what the function is for the second button, it never works. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: you may need to change your window focus

      `var win=window.open("https://www.google.com/?client=safari", '_blank')`
       `win.focus();`